# Pass userform textbox values to excel textbox

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Get_values()
Dim Domain, Project, UserName, Password, Test_Lab_Path
 Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
        "Path\sheetname.xlsm", _
        Origin:=xlWindows
Worksheets("sheetname.xlsm").TextBox5.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox1.Value 'Domain
Worksheets("sheetname.xlsm").TextBox6.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox2.Value 'Project
Worksheets("sheetname.xlsm").TextBox7.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox3.Value 'UserName
Worksheets("sheetname.xlsm").TextBox8.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox4.Value 'Password
Worksheets("sheetname.xlsm").TextBox8.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox5.Value 'Test Lab Path 
End Sub
```

I am trying to get the values from userform called "ALM_Login_Page" and put those values into textboxes of a xlsm sheet. Tried above code but getting error "Run Time error 9, subscript out of range"
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you want to do exactly, but If you want to reference a sheet, you need to type the name of the sheet to the command, not the filename:

Worksheets("sheetname")...

or

Workbooks("Path\sheetname.xlsm").Worksheets("sheetname")...

or if you want to reference to the book then just:

Workbooks("Path\sheetname.xlsm") and not worksheet

O.

---

If you want write into a textbox object on a sheet you must use the next command:

Worksheets("Sheetname").Shapes("TextBoxname").TextFrame.Characters.Text = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox1.Value

be cerful, if you made a textbox, without naming, it gets "Textbox 1" and not "Textbox1" for name. Check it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Oliver, but unfortunately it didnt worked.
I am trying to pass the values of a text box on useform to a text box on excel sheet.
I tried both the ways you suggested, 
`Worksheets("sheetname").TextBox5.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox1.Value
or
Workbooks("Path\sheetname.xlsm").Worksheets("sheetname").TextBox5.Value = ALM_Login_Page.TextBox1.Value`
But still it is giving same error as  "Run Time error 9, subscript out of range"

Comment: I Edited my answer, check it.